# Getting index of an array with cypress returns a "-1" instead

Tags: javascript, node.js, cypress, cypress-cucumber-preprocessor

I'm trying to get the header of table and put in an array in cypress which I've succesfully done but for some reason when I try to log for example `cy.log(tableHeaders.indexOf("Tracking No."))` it returns "-1" but when I log the whole array `cy.log(tableHeaders)` it returns the proper array and also tried getting the array and index on a separate ".js" file without cypress it runs fine. Am I doing it right? Thank you.

```
let tableHeaders = []
    cy.get('.rt-table > .rt-thead > .rt-tr').each((headRow) => {
        cy.wrap(headRow).within(() => {
            cy.get('.rt-th').each((cellDataHead) => {
                    cy.log(cellDataHead.text())
                    tableHeaders.push(cellDataHead.text().trim())
            })
        })
    })
    
cy.log(tableHeaders) // Returns the whole array
cy.log(tableHeaders.indexOf("Tracking No.")) // returns -1
cy.log(tableHeaders.indexOf("Merchant Name")) // returns -1
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Maybe a bit far-fetched, but can you try get the "length" of each property? If the String contains a "null character", it would still display the same, but show a different length (and therefore a different string). Ex: `("test" + '').length == 4`, but `("test" + '\0').length == 5`, while both will be visibly "test". And `trim()` doesn't remove null characters. e.g. `("test" + '\0').trim().length == 5` just like when not having the `trim()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since JavaScript runs asynchronously, So the below lines are executed before there is anything saved in your array.

```
cy.log(tableHeaders.indexOf("Tracking No.")) 
cy.log(tableHeaders.indexOf("Merchant Name"))
```

To make sure that once your data is saved in the array and then only execute your `cy.log` statements you can use `then()`.

```
let tableHeaders = []
cy.get('.rt-table > .rt-thead > .rt-tr').each((headRow) => {
    cy.wrap(headRow).within(() => {
        cy.get('.rt-th').each((cellDataHead) => {
            cy.log(cellDataHead.text())
            tableHeaders.push(cellDataHead.text().trim())
        })
    })
}).then(() => {
    cy.log(tableHeaders)
    cy.log(tableHeaders.indexOf("Tracking No."))
    cy.log(tableHeaders.indexOf("Merchant Name"))
})
```

Comment: is likely also a problem, but he has shown that `cy.log(tableHeaders)` does log all the contents.

Comment: Thank you, @Alapan the code runs perfectly. yeah, I was also wondering why it logged the array in  ```cy.log(tableHeaders)``` anyways thank you both